# Placing Lock Icon on WooCommmerce "Place Order" Checkout Button (WordPress 'ignoring' Changes...)

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, buttons, icon

Trying to do something I thought would be relatively simple.

Here is the default woocommerce "Place order" button

`<button type="submit" class="button alt" name="woocommerce_checkout_place_order" id="place_order" value="Place order" data-value="Place order">Place order</button>`

and Font Awesome has this lock icon `<i class="fa fa-lock"></i>`

All I am trying to do is add this icon within the button, as such:

```
... data-value="Place order"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i> Place order</button>
```

Things I have tried:

1.

Overriding the `payment.php` template in my child theme: `child-theme/woocommerce/checkout/payment.php`.

changed `line 52` --

```
<?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_button_html', '<button type="submit" class="button alt" name="woocommerce_checkout_place_order" id="place_order" value="' . esc_attr( $order_button_text ) . '" data-value="' . esc_attr( $order_button_text ) . '"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i> ' . esc_html( $order_button_text ) . '</button>' ); // @codingStandardsIgnoreLine ?>
```

(just simply added the `<i class="fa fa-lock"></i>` before `Place order`)

So I go to checkout, confirm it is loading my template in my child theme -- and look at the button.

No change.

`<button type="submit" class="button alt" name="woocommerce_checkout_place_order" id="place_order" value="Place order" data-value="Place order">Place order</button>`

2. via functions

   ```
   add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_button_html', 'misha_custom_button_html' );

    function misha_custom_button_html( $button_html ) {
        echo '<pre>';
        var_dump(html_entity_decode($button_html));
        echo '</pre>';
     return $button_html;
    }
   ```

Same thing -- I go back to checkout.

Right above the checkout button I see my `var_dump`

```
'<button type="submit" class="button alt" name="woocommerce_checkout_place_order" id="place_order" value="Place order" data-value="Place order"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i> Place order</button>' (length=190)
```

So it literally shows the correct HTML in the var_dump, but right below it, is the button,

`<button type="submit" class="button alt" name="woocommerce_checkout_place_order" id="place_order" value="Place order" data-value="Place order">Place order</button>`

No change.

I've also tried changing it directly in the function, but for some reason it is not rendering the correct output for the icon! Meaning ignoring the icon html all together.

I can change the text of the button, add stuff before or after it... but for some reason I cannot add this icon html within it.

Very weird, I do not understand it.

Why is this button being so stubborn and how can I add the font awesome icon to the button?

Answer (score 0):

I guess I can just do this with CSS pseudo elements

```
#place_order::before {
    content: "\f023";
    font-family: FontAwesome;
}
```

and shows the icon before.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the functions.php file,

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_button_html', 'customize_order_button_html' );

function customize_order_button_html( $button_html ) {
    $order_button_text = 'Place Order';
    $button_html = '<button type="submit" class="place-order-button button alt' . esc_attr( wc_wp_theme_get_element_class_name( 'button' ) ? ' ' . wc_wp_theme_get_element_class_name( 'button' ) : '' ) . '" name="woocommerce_checkout_place_order" value="' . esc_attr( $order_button_text ) . '" data-value="' . esc_attr( $order_button_text ) . '"><i class="fa fa-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i>' . esc_html( $order_button_text ) . '</button>'; // @codingStandardsIgnoreLine
    return $button_html;
}
```

CSS (change it according to what you want)

```
/* START - Checkout Page */
.place-order-button {font-size:20px!important;margin-top: 20px!important;float: right!important;background: #fdb933 !important;color: #000000!important;border-radius: 5px!important;box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(213,217,217,.5)!important;}
.place-order-button:hover {background: #fdac0c!important;}
.place-order-button i {padding-bottom: 6px;margin-right: 10px;font-size: 22px;}
/* END - Checkout Page */
```